# Why I can't assign function returning rvalue reference when it's a int but I can when it's a class?

Tags: c++

Why we can assign rvalue reference from a non-scalar but from a scalar it does not work, when returning from function, but works in local variable (wtf) ?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <type_traits>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

struct A
{
};

int&& f()
{
    return 10;
}

A&& g()
{
    return {};
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    
    // f() = 10; <-- This line doesn't compile
    g() = A(); // Works

    int&&x = 10;
    x = 20; // Works

  cout << "ok" << endl;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: The assignment fails because `f` returns an r-value. `x` is an l-value in `main`, so you can assign to it.

Comment: Hmm, the target I used to close the question covers one aspect of the question, but not the difference between why `f()` can't be assigned to, but `x` can, so I've reopened it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two things going on in your code. The first is the difference between being able to assign to temporaries (r-values) of class type.

```
struct S{};
S{} = S{};     // ok, S is class type
int{} = int{}; // error, int is an in-built type
```

This explains why `f() = 10;` doesn't work, but `g() = A();` does. `f` returns a r-value of `int`, while `g` returns a r-value of class type (`A`).

---

The second difference is between the *value categories* of `f()` and `x`. While both these expressions have the same *type*, i.e. r-value reference to `int` (`int&&`), the value category of `f()` is an r-value, while that of `x` is an l-value (basically, `x` has a name, whereas the object returned by `f()` doesn't).

```
f() = 10;  // error
x = 20;    // ok
```